# Javascript Login

Tags: javascript, authentication

I am trying to create a login page using JavaScript. It's really just a redirect page with a couple of usernames and passwords. I know how insecure it is, but its simple; plus no confidential information will be on the target pages.

I got my script from this source: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/loginpass2.shtml

Im trying to have certain usernames redirect to a particular page and I want to do that with the code given..I just don't know how.

Sorry for not being clear.

For example, when someone logs in as user 1 I want them to be redirected to a different page as user 2.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: If you are just creating a redirect page, why not just provide static links to your target pages?

Comment: What will you do after redirected second page? If you will use js, you can use cookie or local storage. If you will use PHP like programming language, you need to handle in specified php file

Comment: your question is just not cleared.

Comment: What is the point of having both usernames and passwords in the Javascript source? All it says is a person can view the source and cut'n'paste

Comment: I think OP just wants to redirect the user with a certain username to a certain target page.

Comment: Then why bother with the password.

Comment: If you're going to make a client-side login system, I'd recommend just redirecting the user to /USERNAME/PASSWORD/index.htm. This is the most secure you can get, I think

Comment: Frankly I'm not sure it's the right example to build upon if you want to understand how redirection works. The silly password is just excess luggage that will clutter your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do

```
window.location.replace(url);
```

Where you get url from matching a username with a url. An associated array would fit the bill